# What are the number of samples required to fully cover fixed length string?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many samples do I need to make (in expectation and bounds if existent) from a set of randomly generated binary strings of length $n$ such that there is at least a one at each position $i$.

e.g. for $n=3$ the covering sets are:

1 sample: {111}

2 samples: {101,010},{100,011},{001,110},{000,111},{101,110},{100,111}...

3 samples: {100,010,001},{101,000,010},...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of samples needed to cover all bits.  Then, as André Nicolas
remarked, $P(N \le m) = (1 - 2^{-m})^n$, or $P(N \ge m) = 1 - (1 - 2^{1-m})^n =
\sum_{j=1}^n {n \choose j} (-1)^{j+1} 2^{j(1-m)}$.  We have
$$E[N] = \sum_{m=1}^\infty P(N \ge m) = \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^j}{2^{-j}-1} {n \choose j} $$
The numerators and denominators of these are in OEIS sequences [A158466](http://oeis.org/A158466) and [A158467](http://oeis.org/A158467) respectively.  You may find some of the links at A158466 useful.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we take $m$ samples. Then the probability that the first bit is NOT covered is $1/2^m$. Therefore since there are $n$ bits, we have
$$ \mathbb{P}( \text{some bit is not covered}) \le \frac{n}{2^m}. $$
So if you want this probability to be less than any fixed small value $\alpha$, you can take $m = \log_2 (n/\alpha) $ samples.

Comment: The probability any particular bit is covered is $1-\frac{1}{2^m}$.  So by independence the probability all $n$ bits are covered is $\left(1-\frac{1}{2^m}\right)^n$.